# Issues creating a flipview on ItemDetailPage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, flipview

I am trying to create a flipview on the an ItemDetailpage. I am using the default template provided in visual studio when creating a grid app.

Pages in the App: GroupItemsPage, GroupDetailPage, ItemDetailPage

The problem is, I am getting this error when I click on an item on the GroupItemsPage or GroupDetailPage:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Error details:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147467261
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=AppError
StackTrace: at AppError.ItemDetailPage.<navigationHelper_LoadState>d__0.MoveNext()
```

This is my code:

**GroupItemsPage.xaml**

```
<Page
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="AppError.GroupedItemsPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppError"
xmlns:data="using:AppError.Data"
xmlns:common="using:AppError.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="ChevronGlyph">&#xE26B;</x:String>
    <!--
        Collection of grouped items displayed by this page, bound to a subset
        of the complete item list because items in groups cannot be virtualized
    -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Groups}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="Items"
        d:Source="{Binding Groups, Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid -->
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid GroupPadding="0,0,70,0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2">
                            <Button Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Click="Header_Click"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0,-11,10,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-11,0,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,40"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**GroupItemsPage.xaml.cs**

```
 namespace AppError
 {
  public sealed partial class GroupedItemsPage : Page
  {
    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

    public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
    {
        get { return this.navigationHelper; }
    }

    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }

    public GroupedItemsPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
    }

    private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
        var sampleDataGroups = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupsAsync();
        this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = sampleDataGroups;
    }

    void Header_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Determine what group the Button instance represents
        var group = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;

        // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
        // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(GroupDetailPage), ((SampleDataGroup)group).UniqueId);
    }

    void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
        // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
        var itemId = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage), itemId);
    }
}
```

**GroupDetailpage.xaml**

```
<Page
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="AppError.GroupDetailPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppError"
xmlns:data="using:AppError.Data"
xmlns:common="using:AppError.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        d:Source="{Binding Groups[0].Items, Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    DataContext="{Binding Group}"
    d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[0], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid -->

    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="120,126,120,50"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="110" Width="480" Margin="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="110" Height="110">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.Header>
            <StackPanel Width="480" Margin="0,4,14,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Margin="0,0,0,20" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Height="400" Margin="0,0,0,20" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GridView.Header>
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="52,0,0,2"/>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </GridView>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,40"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**GroupDetailPage.xaml.cs**

```
 namespace AppError
{
  public sealed partial class GroupDetailPage : Page
{
    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

    public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
    {
        get { return this.navigationHelper; }
    }

    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }


    public GroupDetailPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
    }

    private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
        var group = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupAsync((String)e.NavigationParameter);
        this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = group;
        this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = group.Items;
    }

    void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
        // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
        var itemId = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage), itemId);
    }
}
```

**ItemDetailPage.xaml**

```
<Page
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="AppError.ItemDetailPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppError"
xmlns:data="using:AppError.Data"
xmlns:common="using:AppError.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">


<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        d:Source="{Binding Groups[0].Items, Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    DataContext="{Binding Item}"
    d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[0].Items[0], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--
        TODO: Content should be placed within the following grid 
              to show details for the current item
    -->
    <FlipView 
        Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="flipView"
        Margin="50,0,0,0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemViewSource}}">

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Padding="0,30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="30,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>

    </FlipView>



    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                    AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,40"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**ItemDetailPage.xaml.cs**

```
 namespace AppError
{
  public sealed partial class ItemDetailPage : Page
  {
    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

    public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
    {
        get { return this.navigationHelper; }
    }

    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }

    public ItemDetailPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
    }

    private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
        var group = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupAsync((String)e.NavigationParameter);
        var item = await SampleDataSource.GetItemAsync((String)e.NavigationParameter);
        this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = group;
        this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = group.Items;
        this.flipView.SelectedItem = item;
    }
}
```